# Magento 2: Moving Category Description

Tags: magento2, category, category-description

I'm currently trying to move the category description to below the product grid.

Below is the `catalog_category_view.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products" />
        <move element="category.description" destination="content" before="category.products" />
        <move element="category.image" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs" />
        <move element="category.cms" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="catagory-and-product-page-usp-bar" before="breadcrumbs">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">catagory-and-product-page-usp-bar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="usp-bar" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">usp-bar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have tried updating the XML Layout on the category with the following code but nothing seems to change, Anyone got any ideas?

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.description" destination="content" after="category.products" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Code Found:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products" />
        <move element="category.description" destination="content" before="category.products" />
        <move element="category.image" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs" />
        <move element="category.cms" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="catagory-and-product-page-usp-bar" before="breadcrumbs">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">catagory-and-product-page-usp-bar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="usp-bar" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">usp-bar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, your code itself working good..I have checked in my local setup..

```
 <move element="category.description" destination="content" after="category.products" />
```

After that **clear cache**.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: did you add the xml in corect path? could you share the path of overided file?

Comment: I am adding the XML into the the following on the category section in the admin panel, Design>Layout Update XML

Comment: did you get any errors when saving the category?

Comment: i have updated the answer just add above code directly in 'your category'->Design-> Layout Update XML

Comment: Still nothing, I'm fairly new to administering this site so it could have a module overriding the XML layout

Comment: Yes you can check that module in app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Comment: do you need to move category description for every category or particular category?

Comment: So I found the app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml but its contents is exactly what i posted in the OP

Comment: does this file contain any other code?

Comment: File contents is now in OP

Comment: Remove the line  <move element="category.description" destination="content" before="category.products" />

Comment: you can add that code directly in backend for that category itself..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to move category description In 
**Admin >> Category >> Design >> Layout Update XML**

```
 <move element="category.description" destination="content" after="-" />
```

[image]

Don't use any `<page>` and `<body>` tag. Simply paste above code in **Layout Update XML textarea**.

Don't forgot to **clear cache**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Can you please make sure `catalog_category_view.xml` is not overriding anywhere in other modules OR theme.

Comment: @Willdobbo Use my updated code (don't use any `<page>` and `<body>` tag ) to move category description In Admin >> Category >> Design >> Layout Update XML

Comment: Still nothing, I'm fairly new to administering this site so it could have a module overriding the XML layout

Comment: @Willdobbo Please try to use this code
`<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="-" />`

I have added screenshot in my answer. Please see that and use my code as it is.

Comment: Still nothing :( It must be getting over written by a module. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Do you want to move category description for every category or particular category?
My above code will work for single category, if you want to move for all categories then you will need to write the code in `catalog_category_view.xml` file.

Comment: I just want to move it for a single category

Comment: Remove this line from your code.
`<move element="category.description" destination="content" before="category.products" />`

and this code at last before `</body>`

`<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="-" />
`

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try shortly, I was hoping I wouldn't need to change this file due to us being on the cloud platform, I will have to branch prod and try the changes from there! I will let you know the results!

Answer (score 0):

To make it full width in the bottom of product list, edit `catalog_category_view.xml` or make new one -- if not exist.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="category.in.bottom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container clearfix category-in-bottom" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>

    <move element="category.image" destination="category.in.bottom" after="-"/>
    <move element="category.description" destination="category.in.bottom" after="-"/>
    <move element="category.cms" destination="category.in.bottom" after="-"/>
</body>
```

Here we make a new container called `category.in.bottom` and move the category description, category image, and category cms to this new container.

Also dont forget to add css class to clear floated content  `clear: both;` , in the example i add class `clearfix`

Clear layout cache `bin/magento c:f layout`